# Can't make sens of UIStepper (S)

Tags: swift, uistepper

I'm trying to make an app to count different tokens in a board game. I thought it would be easy peasy, but not quite. 
I succeeded in adding one `UIStepper` to count one kind of token, but I don't know how to add the other four. This is what I've got so far:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var theLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var stepper: UIStepper!

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

@IBAction func StepperTapped(sender: UIStepper) {
self.theLabel.text = "\(self.stepper.value)"
}

}
```

I got one action and two outlets.

Comment: What is your question? Adding more steppers?

Comment: Yes. I want totally five steppers counting their own value.

Comment: Then do like you did on the first one. Just add more steppers and more labels.

Comment: I'm trying to rename the outlets and action, but then the build fails:

`import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var GoldLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var GoldStepper: UIStepper!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    @IBAction func StepperTapped(sender: UIStepper) {
        self.GoldLabel.text = "\(self.GoldStepper.value)"
    }

}`

Comment: Next question. How do I remove the .0?
[http://www.bilddump.se/bilder/20160612172433-80.217.157.190.jpeg]

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit
```

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var theLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var stepper: UIStepper!
@IBOutlet weak var theLabel2: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var stepper2: UIStepper!
@IBOutlet weak var theLabel3: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var stepper3: UIStepper!
@IBOutlet weak var theLabel4: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var stepper4: UIStepper!
@IBOutlet weak var theLabel5: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var stepper5: UIStepper!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

@IBAction func StepperTapped(sender: UIStepper) {
    self.theLabel.text = "\(self.stepper.value)"
}

@IBAction func StepperTapped2(sender: UIStepper) {
    self.theLabel2.text = "\(self.stepper2.value)"

}
@IBAction func StepperTapped3(sender: UIStepper) {
    self.theLabel3.text = "\(self.stepper3.value)"
}
@IBAction func StepperTapped4(sender: UIStepper) {
    self.theLabel4.text = "\(self.stepper4.value)"
}
@IBAction func StepperTapped5(sender: UIStepper) {
    self.theLabel5.text = "\(self.stepper5.value)"
}
```

}